# JavaScript clearTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

(I've looked at all similar questions/answers but none of them solve my problem.)

The code:

```
var timeoutHandle;

function showLoader(show) {
    if (show) {
        $('.loader').html('Loading...');
        $('.loader').show();

        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
            if ($('.loader').is(':visible')) {
                $('.loader').html('Still loading...');
            }
        }, 15000);
    }
    else {
        $('.loader').hide();
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    }
}
```

The AJAX function simply calls `showLoader(true)` before calling the server, and then `showLoader(false)` after a result. I still sometimes see the text change from "Loading..." to "Still loading..." long before 15 seconds, so it's as if a timer thread is still running. Is there something wrong with the code above? Or could the problem be with other code..

**edit:** I must add that `showLoader(true)` can be called again (and again) before a response from the server

Comment: What is the function that calls "showLoader"? Can I see that code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should add a check to see if there is already a `timeoutHandle` before creating a new one.

try this:

```
if(timeoutHandle){
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    timeoutHandle = null;
}
timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
    if ($('.loader').is(':visible')) {
        $('.loader').html('Still loading...');
    }
}, 15000);
```

and then in the else case set `timeoutHandle` to null after you clear it like so:

```
clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
timeoutHandle = null;
```

This will eliminate the chance of you creating concurrent timeouts if `showLoader(true)` function is called more than once.

Comment: it didn't work for me : once the timeoutHandle is affected after being nulled , the time count won't restart from scratch but seems it continues from the point where it was before being nulled!

Answer (score 3):

What might be happening is that you're placing multiple calls to `showLoader` since this is a global function you can access it from anywhere, you typically don't want that.

I would consider changing it to a *monad* implementation:

```
function create_loader(elem) {
    var handle = null;

    function show() {
        elem.html('Loading...');
        elem.show();

        if (handle !== null) {
            clearTimeout(handle); // clear the previous one
        }
        handle = setTimeout(function () {
            elem.html('Still loading...');
        }, 15000);
    }

    return {
        show: show,
        clear: function () {
            elem.hide();
            clearTimeout(handle);
            handle = null;
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
var loader = create_loader($(".loader"));
loader.clear();
loader.show();
loader.show(); // each new call to show will reset the 15s timer
loader.show();
loader.show();
loader.clear();
// and you can make another one that operates independently of other one
var another_loader = create_loader($(".anotherLoader"));
```

Now you have a `loader` object that knows about it's own state.

Comment: Very informative, thank you. Omar's solution is more understandable for me though.

Comment: Omar's solution is fine, mine goes a step further. I remove `timeoutHandle` from the global scope, and tie to an instance of a loader. Now just the `loader` is in the global scope and it keeps it's own state.

Comment: +1 for encapsulating the timer id.You could take this one step further and add a callback for when the load finishes.

Comment: Is monad a food group?

Answer (score 1):

In your post you mention that showloader can be called multiple times before the first return.  This is your problem.  You are overwriting an already existing timeoutHandle with a new one without destroying the already existing handle.  You should check if the timeoutHandle is set or not set before you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call **clearTimeout(timeoutHandle)** then starting new request, if timeoutHandle exist